# CakePHP: How can I use a "HAVING" operation when building queries with find method?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to use the "HAVING" clause in a SQL query using the CakePHP paginate() method.

After some searching around it looks like this can't be achieved through Cake's paginate()/find() methods.

The code I have looks something like this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'fields' => $fields,
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'recursive' => 1,
        'limit' => 10, 
        'order' => $order,
        'group' => 'Venue.id');
```

One of the $fields is an alias "distance". I want to add a query for when distance < 25 (e.g. HAVING distance < 25).

I have seen two workarounds so far, unfortunately neither suit my needs. The two I've seen are:

1) Adding the HAVING clause in the "group" option. e.g. `'group' => 'Venue.id HAVING distance < 25'`. This doesn't seem to work when used in conjunction with pagination as it messes up the initial count query that is performed. (ie tries to `SELECT distinct(Venue.id HAVING distance < 25)` which is obviously invalid syntax.

2) Adding the HAVING clause after the WHERE condition (e.g. `WHERE 1 = 1 HAVING field > 25`) This doesn't work as it seems the HAVING clause must come **after** the group statement which Cake is placing after the WHERE condition in the query it generates.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with CakePHP's find() method? I don't want to use query() as that would involve a lot of rework and also mean I'd need to implement my own pagination logic!

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about `conditions => array('Venue.distance <=' => 25)` ?

Comment: @Chetan I mentioned this workaround in the question...it doesn't work for me..

Comment: @Piotr, distance is an alias so can't be used in a WHERE clause

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to put it with the group conditions. like this

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.length >=' => 100
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Author.id', 'COUNT(*) as Total'
    ),
    'group' => array(
        'Total HAVING Total > 10'
    )
));
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is the first workaround I found as described in my question. It doesnt work with pagination as it screws up the COUNT query that is made.

Comment: yep, the pagination breaks with that but, you can still do pagination, you just need to override paginate and paginationCount. [Look here](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/best-paginatecount-cakephp-with-group-by-support) the solution (remember having is in group)

Comment: This is close to what I want. However the count query is trying to filter on the distance alias but that's not getting set up.
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count` I think I need that to be something like:
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, (some sum) AS distance`. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: instead of count(*) put the sum you want and in having Total put having Total <= 10 or any other distannce you want

Answer (score 1):

I used the following trick to add my own HAVING clause at the end of my WHERE clause. The "dbo->expression()" method is mentioned in the cake [sub-query documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries).

```php
function addHaving(array $existingConditions, $havingClause) {
  $model = 'User';
  $db = $this->$model->getDataSource();

  // Two fun things at play here,
  // 1 - mysql doesn't allow you to use aliases in WHERE clause
  // 2 - Cake doesn't allow a HAVING clause separate from a GROUP BY
  // This expression should go last in the WHERE clause (following the last AND)
  $taut = count($existingConditions) > 0 ? '1 = 1' : '';
  $having = $db->expression("$taut HAVING $havingClause");

  $existingConditions[] = $having;

  return $existingConditions;
}
```

Comment: Writing a function to overwrite the convention seems a quite extreme solution when you can simply set `order` properly.

Comment: @rlcabral I don't see the `order` solution mentioned in the answers. Can you describe how that works and still provides the ability to have proper pagination?  This is not to say that I disagree about this being extreme. However, as far as I could tell, the framework does not provide a way to accomplish the requirement... so sometimes you need to take extreme measures!

Comment: You can use the `order` to add `having` like: `'order' => $order . " HAVING $havingClause"`. Not pretty, but it will put the `having` in the right place for the query to work.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find), CakePHP/2 supports `having` at last. It was added as find array parameter on version 2.10.0, [released](https://bakery.cakephp.org/2017/07/22/cakephp_2100_released.html) on 22<sup>nd</sup> July 2017.

From the [2.10 Migration Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-10-migration-guide.html#model):

> `Model::find()` now supports `having` and `lock` options that enable you to
>   add `HAVING` and `FOR UPDATE` locking clauses to your find operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. I know, one is not supposed to modify the internal code but if you open the `PaginatorComponent` and you modify line 188:

```
$count = $object->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
```

to this:

```
$count = $object->find(
             'count', 
             array_merge(array("fields" => $fields),$parameters, $extra)
         );
```

Everything will be fixed. You will be able to add your HAVING clause to the 'group' and the COUNT(*) won't be a problem.

Or, make line:

```
$count = $object->paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra);
```

to include the `$fields`:

```
$count = $object->paginateCount($fields,$conditions, $recursive, $extra);
```

After that, you can "override" the method on the Model and make sure to include the $fields in the find() and that's it!, =P

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea that doesn't solve the pagination issue, but it is clean since it just overrides the find command in AppModel.  Just add a group and having element to your query and this will convert to a HAVING clause.

```
public function find($type = 'first', $query = array()) {
    if (!empty($query['having']) && is_array($query['having']) && !empty($query['group'])) {
      if ($type == 'all') {
        if (!is_array($query['group'])) {
          $query['group'] = array($query['group']);
        }

        $ds = $this->getDataSource();
        $having = $ds->conditions($query['having'], true, false);
        $query['group'][count($query['group']) - 1] .= " HAVING $having";

        CakeLog::write('debug', 'Model->find: out query=' . print_r($query, true));
      } else {
        unset($query['having']);
      }
    }

    return parent::find($type, $query);
  }
```

Found it here

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tickets-cakephp/EYFxihwb55I

Answer (score 0):

Using 'having' in find did not work for me. Instead I put into one string with the group
" group => product_id, color_id having sum(quantity) > 2000 " and works like a charm.
Using CakePHP 2.9